# Window form focus can't be set when form loading?

Tags: c#, winforms

I did search google prior asking this question. Basically I have try one small snake game. My game started on arrow key down. This arrow key working on when focus windows form. if we delete every type of button and control then focus go on windows form, other wise not focus set on windows form. I have just add the button focus set on button. any one help and thanks in advance..

[image]

```
 private void Key_down(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        int xx = pictureBox1.Location.X;
        int yy = pictureBox1.Location.Y;
        i = xx;
        ii = yy;

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
        {
          //  x = x + 1;
           // MessageBox.Show("Test");
       //     pictureBox1.DisplayRectangle = Rectangle.
           cr = true;
           cl = false;
           cu = false;
           cd = false;
         // pictureBox1.Location = new Point(x, y);

        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
        {
            cl = true;
            cr = false;
            cu = false;
            cd = false;
        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
        {
            cu = true;
            cl = false;
            cr = false;
            cd = false;
        }

        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
        {
            cd = true;
            cu = false;
            cr = false;
            cl = false;
        }
      //  pictureBox1.Location = new Point(x, y);

    }
```

Comment: what you can try man??????

Comment: Look at Form KeyPreview and stop worrying about the focus

Comment: i try change the true but problem same....

Comment: plz any one help me........my assignment pending????

Comment: Which events are you using in order to use the arrow keys?

Comment: coding parts showing above.....

Comment: on what exactly you want to set the focus?

Answer (score 1):

this line didn't work for me when i put in Form's Load event

```
    this.Focus();
```

it only worked when i put it in Form's Shown even.
i believe the Focus() method must be called after the form finishes loading.

Answer (score 0):

Add `this.Focus();` as the last line of the Forms load procedure

And if you want to prevent it from losing focus add a timer and in the `.tick` procedure add `this.Focus();` and set the interval to 1000 so it checks every second that the form has focus

Hope this helps

Comment: short, to the point...and might not work.  Then again, it might.  This is probably the first thing I would try.

Answer (score 0):

`JamesB` added the correct answer in comments: you just need to set the `KeyPreview` property of your form to `true`, and then your KeyDown method will receive all key events, regardless of which control on the form has the focus. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview.aspx